# Скрыть дубли строк при checked

Tags: jquery

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
$('.problem').change(function({ target: t }) {
  const { type, problem } = t.dataset;
  $(`a[data-type="${type}"][data-problem="${problem}"]`).toggle(t.checked);
}).find('input').change();
});
</script>

<div class="remont">
<div class="problem">
<input data-type="Стиральная машина" data-problem="Не стирает" type="checkbox" value="Не стирает">
<input data-type="Стиральная машина" data-problem="Мигает" type="checkbox" value="Мигает">
<input data-type="Стиральная машина" data-problem="Течет" type="checkbox" value="Течет">
</div>

<div class="price-problem">
<a data-type="Стиральная машина" data-problem="Не стирает" href="#" class="price__item">Сломалась</a>
<a data-type="Стиральная машина" data-problem="Мигает" href="#" class="price__item">Сломалась</a>
<a data-type="Стиральная машина" data-problem="Течет" href="#" class="price__item">Течет</a>
</div>

</div>
```

При выбранном checkbox, скрываются/показываться ссылки в price-problem, с привязкой. Выбрано может быть несколько чекбоксов, соответственно нужно показывать все выбранные, скрывать все не выбранные, что код ниже и делает. Выбираем "Не стирает, мигает" - скрываются в price-problem "Течет", остальные показываются. Но так как checked, может быть несколько, необходимо скрывать дубли.

Подскажите как скрыть дубли? Выбираем "Не стирает, Мигает". Появиться дубли, 2 раза "Не стирает". Вот как в таком случае скрыть дубли при двойном checkbox?

Comment: Это не дубли у вас, а разные ссылки с одинаковым текстом.

Comment: Не морозит (Замена компрессора,Замена терморегулятора,Замена термостата,Замена реле)
Покрывается льдом (Замена испарителя,Замена терморегулятора,Замена испарителя)
Работает только морозилка(Замена терморегулятора,Замена компрессора, Замена терморегулятора)
Перемораживает(Замена компрессора,Замена термостата)

Comment: В этом и проблема, что по такому принципу только с дублями получается сделать, т.к. на каждый тип может быть свой набор проблем...а как по другому сделать не знаю. А если выбрать несколько проблем, то вылезут дубли, т.к. они в наборе каждого в разной последовательности имеются

Answer (score 1):

а почему у вас

```
<a data-type="Стиральная машина" data-problem="Мигает" href="#" class="price__item">Не стирает</a>
```

а не

```
<a data-type="Стиральная машина" data-problem="Мигает" href="#" class="price__item">Мигает</a>
```

**Updated.**

Это не дубли. А разные ссылки. Если вам нужно генерировать одну ссылку в зависимости от выбора то так и пишите. Что у вас есть цена услуг по выбору которых будет создана ссылка с суммой и перечнем услуг.

Comment: И верните галочку на вчерашний ответ автору

Comment: Проблем может быть несколько. И для каждой могут быть одинаковые варианты.

Например. Выбран тип проблемы "Не стирает и Мигает" - и варианты что эта проблема означает и там и там, к примеру "Сломалась". Получаются дубли.

Comment: поставил я галочку

Comment: Не морозит (Замена компрессора,Замена терморегулятора,Замена термостата,Замена реле) Покрывается льдом (Замена испарителя,Замена терморегулятора,Замена испарителя) Работает только морозилка(Замена терморегулятора,Замена компрессора, Замена терморегулятора) Перемораживает(Замена компрессора,Замена термостата)

В этом и проблема, что по такому принципу только с дублями получается сделать, т.к. на каждый тип может быть свой набор проблем...а как по другому сделать не знаю. А если выбрать несколько проблем, то вылезут дубли, т.к. они в наборе каждого в разной последовательности имеются

Comment: Да не мне же галочку

Comment: он удалил свое решение, не знаю как сделать это

Comment: Генерируйте ссылку в которой будет сумма и перечень услуг

Comment: а можно пример?

Comment: Да чуток попозже